# A triangle where two of its sides are diameters of circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given an acute triangle $\triangle XYZ$ and two circles with diameters $XY$ and $YZ$, the circles intersect at two points. One of the intersection points is obviously at $Y$ by construction.

Is the other intersection point $W$ inside, outside, or on $\triangle XYZ$? How to prove it?

[image]

Comment: initial back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest that $W$ is inside the triangle $XYZ$ iff $Z$ lies outside the circle having $XY$ as diameter, and $ZX$ is less than $ZY$

Comment: Let $P$ and $Q$ be the centers of the circles (aka, the midpoints of $XY$ and $YZ$). Reflect $Y$ over $PQ$ to get $Y^\prime$. Then $|PY^\prime| = |PY|$ and $|QY^\prime|=|QY|$, so $Y^\prime$ is the other point of intersection of the two circles. Moreover, since the distance from $Y$ to $PQ$ is half the altitude from $Y$ to $XZ$, it follows that $Y^\prime$ lies on $XZ$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb C$. By a [Moebius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
$F$ interchange point $Y$ with $\infty$. Such a Moebius maps sends:

Lines not through $Y$ to circles through $Y$.

Lines through $Y$ to lines through $Y$.

Circles through $Y$ to lines not through $Y$.

Circles not through $Y$ to circles through $Y$

So:

The line $L$ between $X,Z$ is mapped to the circle $C=F(L)$ trough $F(X),F(Z),Y$.

The circle $C_1$ whose diameter is $ZY$ is mapped to a line $A_1$ through $F(Z),Y$

The circle $C_2$ whose diameter is $X,Y$ is mapped to a line $A_2$ through $F(X),Y$

The line $L_1$ through $ZY$ is mapped to a line $B_1$ through $F(Z),Y$

The line $L_2$ through $XY$ is mapped to a line $B_2$ through $F(X),Y$

Since $C_1$ and $L_1$ are perpendicular and moebius maps are conformal, then $A_1$ and $B_1$ are perperndicular at $F(Z)$

Same reasoning for $A_2$ and $B_2$ that are then perpendicular at $F(X)$.

It follows that $P=A_1\cap A_2$ is the other point of the diameter of $C$ opposite to $Y$, and that triangles $\Delta YF(Z)P$ and $\Delta YF(X)P$ are the two rectangle triangles inscribed in $C$ with diameter $YP$.

Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersects at $W$, then $A_1$ and $A_2$ intersect at $F(W)$.

So $P=F(W)$, hence $F(W)\in C=F(L)$ and so $W\in L$.

(A picture would help...)